# show button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am developing MVC 5 application. There is one table in that one column contains 2 images side by side.  when I click first row first image I need to show one button at the bottom, everything works fine as of now, but the problem is when I click the image in the second row it is  not showing the button at the bottom.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#lnkCompare").click(function () {  
  $(".DetailsMerge").css('display', 'inline-block');   
});
```

Button code:

```
<input type="button" class="form-button DetailsMerge" 
  value="Merge" id="btnMerge" style="display:none" 
  onclick="javascript: btnMergeCustomer(@TempData["Newcustomerid"]);" />
```

Comment: What is your HTML? Is every `id` unique?

Comment: yes, every id is unique

Answer (score 1):

Using inline-styles is not a recommended way of displaying or hiding content.  I would suggest using a class to hide the element then use the .addClass & .removeClass to enable the toggling (or simply .toggleClass if it is very simple).

CSS Stylesheet

```
.h{display:none}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="form-button DetailsMerge h" value="Merge" id="btnMerge" onclick="javascript: btnMergeCustomer(@TempData["Newcustomerid"]);" />
```

JS

```
$("#lnkCOmpare").click(function(){
    $("#btnMerge").removeClass("h");
});
```

Comment: Hi Michael - Thanks for reply, but its not working. its not showing the button even click the first row of image. using my code it shows the button when I click the first row of image.

Comment: make sure you don't have 2 elements titled "#btnMerge" as the ID element.  If you have to repeat this multiple times on multiple button clicks, I would suggest wrapping each button/image in a parent div with a common class and then using $(this).closest('.common_div_class').find('.DetailsMerge').removeClass('h').

Comment: Ha, just realized that you are trying to show/hide the button itself.  Please add more of your HTML code (you need to show both the button and the image code) and I will update this answer with the correct code.

Comment: Using this  http://jsfiddle.net/h46uw7qo/  code it is showing the button by default without clicking the image button.

Comment: As I mentioned, without the actual HTML (it appears you're using ASP.net which I am not familiar with), I cannot provide the EXACT solution, but I still stand by my previous two assertions: use classes to hide elements then .removeClass to show them and you're probably running into an issue with hard-coding ID's.  Here is an updated example of having an "Image" button and then clicking it to show the "Merge" button. http://jsfiddle.net/h46uw7qo/1/

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "_CompareCustomerDetails", new { ExistingCustomerId =        item.customer_id, NewCustomerId = TempData["NewCustomerID"] }, new AjaxOptions() 
{ HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "divCustomerCompare", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace                                                                                                   
}
,new { id =   "lnkCompare" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img             src=\"images/icons/compare3.jpg\"class=\"linkCompare\" title='Compare' />"))

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        $(".DetailsMerge").hide();
    });
        $("#lnkCompare").click(function () { 
        $(".DetailsMerge").css('display', 'inline-block');      
    });
});
```

```
 <input type="button" class="form-button DetailsMerge" value="Merge" id="btnMerge"    style="display:none" onclick="javascript: btnMergeCustomer(@TempData["Newcustomerid"]);" />
```

Comment: Is your $("#btnSearch").click() function working if you remove the style from the HTML?

Comment: Hmm, still don't have a good picture of your HTML (not a markup language you use, but the actual HTML from the developer console).  If the first image is working and the second image isn't working, I would still be leaning towards the fact you are using ID's (#btnSearch/#lnkCompare) to call the function and classes to toggle the buttons (.DetailsMerge).  Most likely, you are reusing your ID's

Comment: I remove the style function from button code but its not working.